# how i can add a http api stage in serverless

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless, aws-http-api

I am trying to deploy a serverless application to different stages (prod and dev). I want to deploy it to a single API gateway on two different stages
like:-
http://vfdfdf.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/
http://vfdfdf.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/

I have written a code in serverless -

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  region: ${self:custom.${self:custom.stage}.lambdaRegion}
  httpApi: 
    id: ${self:custom.${self:custom.stage}.httpAPIID}
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Edited to reflect the comments*

That can be done during the serverless deployment phase.

I would just have the `dev` by default in the serverless yml file

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  stage: dev
  region: eu-west-1
  httpApi:
    # Attach to an externally created HTTP API via its ID:
    id: w6axy3bxdj
    # or commented on the very first deployment so serverless creates the HTTP API

custom:
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /${self:custom.stage}/hello
          method: get
```

Then, the command:

`serverless deploy`

deploys in stage `dev` and region here `eu-west-1`. It's using the default values.

```
endpoint: GET - https://w6axy3bxdj.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/hello
```

While for production, the default values can be overridden on the command line. Then I would use the command:

`serverless deploy --stage prod`

```
endpoint: GET - https://w6axy3bxdj.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/hello
```

---

In my understanding, you do not change the region between `dev` and `prod`; but in case you would want to do that. The production deployment could be:

`serverless deploy --stage prod --region eu-west-2`

to deploy in a different region than the default one from the serverless yml file.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this it will create a cloud formation and lambda prefix with stage, but did not use gateway stage like /dev for --stage dev & /prod for -- stage prod with http api gateways

Comment: Right, this is a difference between REST API and HTTP API. let me quicky change the response above, still using the same pattern, default is dev in the yml file and production on the command line

Comment: i don't want to write these line of code in every function.
         path: /${self:custom.stage}/hello